# Not verified Email on Device (Firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to register a user and verify their email. I've done it and verified it on the email but on Auth.auth().currentUser.isEmailVerified

```
    if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)! {
        // present another vc
    } else {
        print("not verified yet") //Always prints that
    }
```

here's my sendVerificationEmail function:

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            user.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error)
                return
            }
                print("Sent VerificationMail")
        })
    } else {
        print("no user logged in")
    }
```

here i register the user:

```
func registrateUser(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        result?.user.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error)
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            completion(true)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload user profile before checking if email is verified.

Use following code:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        // handle error
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    // your code below
    if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)! {
        // present another vc
    } else {
        print("not verified yet") //Always prints that
    }
})
```